# Jquery UI Date Picker: Implementing Alternate Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have my Jquery UI Date Picker insert YYYY/MM/DD format (due to SQL limitations). I see the options on the [Jquery site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat), but can't get it to work. Below is my working code (without Alt Date). It's in a div that is hidden initially so it needs live():

```
$(function() { 
    $('.datepicker').live('focus', function () {
        var picker = $(this).datepicker({showOn: ''});
        picker.datepicker("show");

    });
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `"option", "dateFormat", "yy/mm/dd"` to your datepicker call.

```
    var picker = $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd", showOn: ''});
```

This will make datepicker format the date value selected as 2011/08/22.